# Complexity of find histogram bins vs convex hull

Tags: time-complexity, space-complexity

For a list of n 2d points, finding the convex hull vertex takes O(n log(n)) time. And O(n) time if it’s sorted lexicon order.

Meanwhile What’s the complexity of finding the histogram bin edges of k bins on both axis ?

E.g.:
$$
X= ((x_0, a_0), (x_1, a_1), \cdots, (x_n, a_n)), x_i \in \mathbf{R}, a_i \in \mathbf{R}
$$

Finding the extreme points of the convex hull of $X$ vs Finding the edges for $K$ histogram bins for both $(x_0, x_1, \cdots x_n)$ and $(a_0, a_1, \cdots, a_n)$.

Which one is faster ?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific when you say "histogram bin edges of k bins on both axis?"

Comment: thanks, I have updated the problem

Comment: You still haven't clarified how your histogram bin edges are supposed to be placed, and how it applies to 2D. Do you want a histogram separately over each dimension, or directly in 2D? Please elaborate.

Comment: Separately over each dimension